# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string'

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I ma getting an error

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string'

while finding out volume through a c# code and oracle query:

```
public DataTable empcount(string strtdate, string enddate)
{

        string cString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["greft"].ToString();

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cString);
        OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand();
        cmd2.CommandText = "Select (sum(emp)) from emp_rec where emp_typ = 'M'and emp_stat!= 'ON'and trunc(join_start) >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:sdate, 'DD-MM-YY'), 'DD-MON-YY') and trunc(join_end) <= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:edate, 'DD-MM-YY'), 'DD-MON-YY') ";
        cmd2.Parameters.Add(":sdate", strtdate);
        cmd2.Parameters.Add(":edate", enddate);
        cmd2.Connection = conn;
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd2);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();           
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Dispose();
        return dt;
}
```

In the table the `join_start` and `join_end` has date in the format like '02-MAY-2019'. The :sdate & :edate input will be in the format of mm/dd/yyyy (e.g. 05/01/2019).

Comment: Instead of strings, it would be better to use `DateTime` in C# relevant type on Oracle side, On the other hand, your `'02-MAY-2019` and `05/01/2019` strings format clearly don't match.

Answer (score 1):

The column `REQ_START_TIME` is of data type `VARCHAR2(11)` with values such as `02-MAY-2019`

The parameter value `sdate`  is a String with values such as `05/01/2019`

I see two problems

**Trunc on a character column**

`trunc(REQ_START_TIME)`  - you should convert the string to `DATE` before truncating it (or  even better store the value in a `DATE` column!)

**Mask 'DD-MM-YY'  for the value `05/01/2019`**

Convert the predicate to

```
where trunc(to_date(REQ_START_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY')) >=  TO_DATE(:sdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

**Generall recommendation - do not store a `DATE` values in a character column in the database**

Comment: @shekhar In doubt, pass the `sdate` as String (e.g. `05/01/2019`) and let the database convert it to `DATE`. I updated the answer.

Comment: As per my understanding i have done the same. Can you share the code to me here please

Comment: Remove `Convert.ToDateTime(strtdate)` and retry @shekhar